# PyCharm Vim plugin line wrapping

Tags: vim, pycharm, ideavim

In PyCharm with the Vim plugin, how do I make it so that the cursor will wrap lines (go from beginning of one line to the end of the previous or vice versa)?

The .vimrc is:

```
set whichwrap=<,>,h,l,[,]
```

but there's no way to configure a .vimrc in PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdeaVim plug-in [already reads](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-134) `.vimrc`, but it doesn't support all the options as it emulates only a part of the vim functionality. If certain option is not supported, submit a feature request to the [IdeaVim issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/VIM).

Note that it's an open source plug-in, if you really need this feature, try adding it yourself and send a pull request or a patch to the vendors.